# Abrir base de datos sql 2014 en sql server 2012

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

Tengo dos consultas

1. Me encuentro desarrollando una aplicación usando SQL server 2014
   enterprise, pero quisiera saber si esta BD la puedo migrar a un
   servidor SQL Server 2012 Enterprise o Standar. Si es que se puede
   realizar ¿Es el mismo proceso para realizarlo (Adjuntar-Restaurar)?
2. Si NO se puede realizar esta migración, tendría que crear una base
   de datos en SQL server 2012 y pasar objeto por objeto (tablas,
   procedimientos, vistas, indices, otros) o hay alguna forma de
   realizarlos rapidamente?

Comment: si pero debes dar la opcion `script` que creara las secuencias de comandos para recrear la base de datos.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que necesito la estructura  y la informacion de la base de datos sql 2014 pasarla a una bd sql 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacerlo con las opcion **generar script.**

te vas a a `tareas->generar script`
en **opciones** le das a **avanzado**

1. version de base de datos = seleccionas la version que deseas
2. secuencia de comandos = schema y datos
3. key      =true
4. Triggers = true
5. Indexes  = true

y ya con esto tendrias un backup es forma de script donde estara toda las structura y los datos en forma de comandos como si ejecutaras intruccion por intruccion

ya solo seria importar en la version antigua...

Comment: Esto es una mala idea porque puede producir un archivo enorme que no podrá ser abierto por Management Studio. Pero no voto de forma negativa porque teóricamente es correcta.

Comment: Gracias, había olvidado esta opción del SQL server, esto me ayuda ya que mi BD recién la estoy empezando a crear, pero lo hice en sql 2014 y el servidor donde la voy a poner es sql 2012

Comment: Lo que indica @LuisCazares es correcto, sin embargo recién estoy empezando con mi BD así que el script aun es pequeño

Comment: @LuisCazares para base de datos demaciados grandes se recomiendo hacer el import por linea de comandos con `sqlcmd`

Answer (score 0):

No por los métodos estándar. Pero puedes exportar en formato **BACPAC** y luego importarlo, aunque en ocasiones me ha dado algún problema con versiones antiguas de SMSS.

En la versión inglesa la opción se llama "**Export Data-Tier Application**", en español "**Exportar aplicación de capa de datos**". Eso lo consigues mediante el menú contextual de la base de datos --> Tareas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego haces el camino contrario. En el menú contextual de la carpeta de las bases de datos verás "**Import Data-Tier Application**" o bien "**Importar aplicación de capa de datos**"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]